# using c# class files from another website on the same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, class, web

hopefully this is a quick one. If I have c# class files on WebsiteA.com - can I reference them in WebsiteB.com? Both sites are on the same server, so I was hoping to reference them on a static address? (d:/inetpub/wwwroot/websiteA-com/app_code/MyClass.cs)

Is this possible? Or - do I have to copy the class file to WebsiteB.com and simply use that?

I just want to avoid repetition when I need to make any changes - avoiding changing both sites.

I've built both sites in .net 4 using visual studio 2010 express.

Thanks

Comment: check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/61834/how-to-setup-an-app-code-virtual-directory-in-iis7) question on serverfault, which might help you, although the answers below are fine as well IMO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you, I would take all the classes needed by both websites and create a Class Library Project (DLL). Then reference that project in each website and use the classes. This means each site will be deployed with the same DLL but you will have a single project for common classes.

Hope this helps (I know it's not strictly the answer)

Comment: thank you - this looks like it's going to be the way forward!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

I don't think that adding the class from the app pool of the IIS folder is a good idea though.

I believe it's a better practice though to make a class library as a separate project called for example Shared and reference it in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Studio you can "Add existing" then choose the "Link" option to add source code from another project

this can be much easier to manage than a shared class library - you can even include the same code in wildly different projects (compact framework, different versions of dot net, etc.)